# jqPlot minimum tick interval

Tags: jqplot

I'm creating the following jqlot

```
    $.jqplot('chartdiv', JSON.parse(response.occnum), {
      title:  'Occurrences',        
      legend: {
           show: true,
           renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
           placement: "outsideGrid",
           labels: response.labels,
           location: "ne",
           rowSpacing: "0px",
           rendererOptions: {
               // set to true to replot when toggling series on/off
               // set to an options object to pass in replot options.
               seriesToggle: 'normal',
               seriesToggleReplot: {resetAxes: true}
           }
      },
      seriesDefaults: {renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer},
      axes: {
          xaxis:{
            label: 'Months',
            tickOptions : {
              tickInterval: 1}
          },               
          yaxis: {
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            labelOptions:{
                fontFamily:'Helvetica'
                //fontSize: '14pt'
            },                
            label: 'Occurrences number'
          }
       }         
    });
```

feeding the plot with following data

```
[[[7,4]],[[4,2],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1],[8,1]],[[5,2],[6,10],[7,6],[8,1]]]
```

and getting as a result

[image]

I want at x-axis to get only integer values 0, 1, 2, 3 and not 0.0, 0.5, 0.1 etc that I'm getting now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `formatString` option to format the xaxis ticks as Integers.

```
tickOptions : {
          formatString:'%d',
          tickInterval: 1}
      },
```

If you'll get repetition of ticks (1, 1, 2, 2...) you can additionally add the `numberTicks` option which sets the exact number of ticks which will be displayed. [Read about it here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.ticks)